# Skype crashing on Ubuntu mate 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype, mate

Sometimes Skype silently crashes. When I open the windows, they are just grey.

I have to close them with `xkill`, and can't reopen Skype. When I try, I just get the clicking sound and see some "stripes" on the left of the screen.

Comment: Does skype running good on another desktop environment?

Comment: What do you mean with another desktop enviroment?

Comment: I only have Ubuntu Mate on this computer.

Comment: I mean, have you tried to run skype on your installation, but using another desktop environment? Also, can you run Skype from console and give us output?

Comment: Run skype from console and give us console output

Comment: When I write skype in the terminal, it don't write/give me anything.

Comment: Wrote "killall -9 skype" and then I could open it. Why?

Comment: It's strange, looks like you can have two instances of skype running at time. Can you issue `ps -ef | grep -i skype` next time you see this thins and update question with this info?

Comment: 7657  1744  0 16:23 ?        00:00:28 skype
8810  8786  0 18:02 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i skype   This is what I get. I think it happends when the computer goes into suspend on its own.